# How to read a text file using Object-Oriented Programming in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, object

I am trying to read a text file in Python using a new Class and OOP but I can't find the right way to do it without using imperative programming like this.

```
def read_operators_file(file_name):
        in_file=open(file_name)
        for i in range(constants.HEADER_TOTAL_LINES):
            in_file.readline()
        operators=[]
        for line in in_file:
            name, nationality, domain, hours, duration = line.strip().split(', ')
            duration=int(duration)
            domain=tuple(domain.strip('(').strip(')').split('; '))
            operators.append((name, nationality, domain, hours, duration))
        in_file.close()
        return operators


def read_requests_file(file_name):
        in_file = open(file_name)
        for i in range(constants.HEADER_TOTAL_LINES):
            in_file.readline()
        requests = []
        for line in in_file:
            name, language, domain, service, duration = line.strip().split(', ')
            duration = int(duration)
            requests.append((name, language, domain, service, duration))
        in_file.close()
        return requests
```

Thanks,
mikeysantana

Comment: You can certainly wrap those functions in a class, but what's the benefit of using a class? Do you need some state to survive between invocations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you certainly *could* convert this to an OOP style, I don't think that it would help much. Instead, I'd suggest trying an [FP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) style. You can define another function, taking the different conversion functions as parameters, e.g. `str` as basically no-operation, `int`, or a `lambda` for more complex stuff. Also, you should use `with` for opening files.

Something like this (not tested):

```
def read_fields(file_name, functions):
    with open(file_name) as in_file:
        for i in range(constants.HEADER_TOTAL_LINES):
            in_file.readline()
        result = []
        for line in in_file:
            fields = [f(x) for f, x in zip(functions) line.strip().split(', ')]
            result.extend(fields)
        return result

def read_operators_file(file_name):
    f_domain = lambda d: tuple(d.strip('(').strip(')').split('; '))
    # fields:                    name nat  domain    hrs  dur
    return read_fields(file_name, (str, str, f_domain, str, int))

def read_requests_file(file_name):
    # fields:                    name lang domn serv dur
    return read_fields(file_name, (str, str, str, str, int))
```

Or using a generator function:

```
def read_fields(file_name, functions):
    with open(file_name) as in_file:
        for i in range(constants.HEADER_TOTAL_LINES):
            in_file.readline()
        for line in in_file:
            yield from (f(x) for f, x in zip(functions) line.strip().split(', '))
```